# Model items passed to Dictionary is of type error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following in my MVC 5 Application.  I have 3 Tabs for cars of Fuel Type which are Diesel/Petrol/Electric.  I have these in 3 Partial Views - something like:

```
@model MyProj.DieselviewModel

<p>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_CarDetails"); } 
</p>
```

The partial for Petrol and Electric then take a PetrolViewModel and ElectricViewModel respectively and all three render the partial view _CarDetails which takes a CarDetailsViewModel.

Note my DieselViewModel is at below:

```
 public class DieselViewModel : CarDetailsViewModel
    {
        public override CarFuelTypeEnum CarFuelType
        {
            get { return CarFuelTypeEnum.Diesel; }
            set { base.CarFuelType = value; }
        }
    }
```

So the fuel type Enum is set here for each Fuel Type and then in the CarDetailsViewModel I have:

```
public virtual CarFuelTypeEnum CarFuelType{ get; set; }
```

So in my _CarDetails Partial view I know which FuelType is set using a ModelBuilder class I have which uses Generics to new up a model of Type T() which will be either the DieselViewModel/PetrolViewModel or ElectricViewModel.

This works nicely until I want to create another partial view in my _CarDetails page - to render some other detail:

So my CarDetailsViewModel is something like (most propertys removed for simplicity)

```
 public class CarDetailsViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public SomeOtherClass OtherClass{ get; set; }    

        public class SomeOtherClass
        {
            public double Field1{ get; set; }
        }
    }
```

My _CarDetails partial then is like:

```
@model MyProj.CarDetailsViewModel

@Html.RenderPartial("_AnotherPartial", Model.OtherClass);
```

the model defined at the top of _AnotherPartial is:

```
@model MyProj.CarDetailsViewModel.OtherClass
```

However even though I am attempting to pass that model class into _AnotherPartial I get an error thrown here saying I am passing a CarDetailsViewModel but the dictionary requires a model of type `'DieselViewModel`' or `PetrolViewModel` or `ElectricViewModel` which is my very first parent view

However with my definition of a DieselViewModel - `public class DieselViewModel : CarDetailsViewModel` isnt it a CarDetailsViewModel that I can then pass to _AnotherPartial page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this error if you have not initialized a new instance of the nested class. In `CarDetailsViewModel`, add a constructor to ensure its initialized

```
public CarDetailsViewModel()
{
  OtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();
}
```

When a model is null, it falls back to the `ViewDataDictionary`, which is `DieselViewModel`, but you actually want `DieselViewModel.SomeOtherClass`. In this case the error message is slightly misleading because the it should say *..but the dictionary requires a model of type **DieselViewModel.SomeOtherClass***. This appears to be a minor bug in that it does not include the nested class.

Another option is to move `SomeOtherClass` outside `CarDetailsViewModel` (i.e. not nested) and  change `_AnotherPartial.cshtml` to `@model MyProj.OtherClass`. In this case if you did not initialise it, you would receive the error message *..but the dictionary requires a model of type **DieselViewModel.SomeOtherClass*** which confirms my suspicion that its a bug

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your first layer, where you have `DieselViewModel`, et al. as model for the view is getting a `CarDetailsViewModel`. You can pass `DieselViewModel` for `CarDetailsViewModel`, but not the other way around.